# With all the easy Django utilities, tools, configs, settings, etc. is there REALLY no easy way to define the name of a custom App in Admin?

Tags: django, admin

How can I make LadyGagaApp into "Lady Gaga App" when displayed in Admin. Option #1 is to explain how to make this happen in the definition of the app, or in settings, or in **init**, etc. Option #2 is to point me to the admin template page where this can be overridden with an example.

Many thanks all.

/Joe

Comment: +1 but.. the django admin is really just for admins.. does it really matter that there's no space?

Comment: The Django admin is enormously configurable, and part of the reason is to allow deployment of a user-friendly admin interface to my clients' sites' administrators (who are not programmers). To that end, refining and tailoring each interface for each of them, I want to use friendly names for all apps, models, and fields among other tweaks. The Lady Gaga example is only just that, an example, in many cases, the app name would be much less discernible for end users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible right now. There is a Django [ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3591) open for this.

Comment: This is probably the best answer at this moment after I dug all the way into this issue. Not sure why this patch doesn't make it into a release. One answer that came close but not all the way was the suggestion to specify the app_label field in the meta for all models in an app to the verbose name you want and make sure they are all the same. This almost works, meaning it gets admin to display the right values, but it causes problems with syncdb, the contenttypes table, and admin permissions for those models.

Comment: You end up having to make sure your DB model is frozen, then add the app_label and db_table properties to each model and manually modify the contenttypes and user permissions table rows to reflect everything correctly. A poor option clearly. I also ran into problems using this method with django-haystack which would not find models with search_indexes.py defined if the app_label did not match the actual app name. The ticket referred to in the answer above is really where this issue needs to be tracked

Answer (score 0):

MYYN is right, open the class "Meta" inside of your model, and set "verbose_name" to "Lady Gaga App."

Comment: If you like an answer, **VOTE FOR IT**.

Comment: that would only change the name of the _model_, not the _app_.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work:

http://packages.python.org/django-admin-tools/0.3.0/index.html

Comment: It's a nice enhancement to admin but it doesn't have the option to override the auto-generated application names in admin.

Comment: are you sure? http://packages.python.org/django-admin-tools/0.3.0/dashboard.html#the-modellist-class